# Opencv-python, face recognition problem, camera turnoff automatically

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, overloading, resolution, face-recognition

I am trying to detect faces through OpenCV module but facing a problem when my camera is turned on after running the code, it turns off automatically and shows me some errors, please take a look at I Would appreciate your help.

Thank you

```
for (top,right,bottom,left), name in zip (self.face_location,self.face_names):
                top*=4
                right*=4
                bottom*=4
                left*=4
                
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(left,top), (right, bottom), (0,0,255),2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(left,bottom-35),(right,bottom),(0,0,255),-1)
                cv2.putText(frame, name,(left + 6,bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0,8,(255,255,255), 2)
                
            cv2.imshow('Face recognition', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1)== ord('q'):
                break
```

OutPut Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/HP/Desktop/facerecogniation/main.py", line 94, in <module>
    fr.run_recognition()
  File "c:/Users/HP/Desktop/facerecogniation/main.py", line 82, in run_recognition
    cv2.putText(frame, name,(left + 6,bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0,8,(255,255,255), int(2))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'putText'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Argument 'thickness' is required to be an integer
>  - Argument 'thickness' is required to be an integer
```

I need help with this. If you know why this error occurs, please let me know. I will be very grateful.

Comment: @toyotaSupra again same error.